# JPanel is sometimes moved to the top left after starting the program

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In my program I use a JFrame and set it's content pane to a JPanel via `setContentPane()`. Sometimes the JPanel is moved to the top left by about 10 to 15 pixels so on the right and on the bottom are white areas.

I tested the panel's position, size and insets but they all are the same as they are without the issue.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DrawPanel dp;

    public Window(int width, int height, String title) {
        dp = new DrawPanel(); // constructor only calls setFocusable(true);

        setResizable(false);
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(title);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setContentPane(dp);
        setVisible(true);

        dp.init(); // only initializes a BufferedImage
    }

    public DrawPanel getDrawPanel() {
        return dp;
    }
```

}

Upper picture is how it is supposed to be, lower picture shows the problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxw26.png]

I hope you understand my problem and can help me. Thank you

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Call `setResizable(false);` followed by either `path` or `setSize`, `setResizable` will change the size of the frame decorations on some platforms

Comment: I tried calling `setResizable(false);` before setSize but the problem is still there. Using Windows by the way.

Comment: So what is the difference between the upper and lower pictures? You got it to work properly once, so figure out what the difference is and fix it. Since you haven't posted your code as asked for twice, we can't really help.

Comment: In the lower picture you can see that on the right and bottom there are white areas which aren't supposed to be there. The problem is that this issue appears randomly at about 15% of the program starts and I can't figure out why this happens.

Comment: `The problem is that this issue appears randomly at about 15% of the program starts` - your code is not executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which can cause random problems. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).   for more information. You still have not posted code that we can compile/execute. (1-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem thanks to [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr)'s comment. I used the `invokeAndWait` method in `SwingUtilities`. Now the JFrame and the JPanel run on the `Event Dispatch Thread` and the issue isn't appearing anymore.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dp = new DrawPanel();

        setResizable(false);
        setSize(width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(title);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setContentPane(dp);
        setVisible(true);

        dp.init();
    }
});
```

Thank you [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr).